# Generalize a problem regarding an inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have proved that the matrix A with dimensions $NxN$ \begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 &...& 1 \\
1 & 0 &...& 1 \\
...&... & ... & ...\\
1 &...&...&0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
has $det(A)=(-1)^{N-1}(N-1)$ and also that the matrix A has an inverse, which is $$A^{-1}={E\over {n-1}}-I$$, where E is the matrix with $e_{ij}=1, i, j\leq N$.

Now, I found that the matrix $B$ with dimensions $NxN$

\begin{equation*}
B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a+b & a &...& a \\
a & a+b &...& a \\
...&... & ... & ...\\
a &...&...&a+b
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

has a determinant $det(B)=b^{N-1}(Na+b)$, and I tried, without much success to find (if it is possible) to find the inverse of the matrix $B$.
I think that I have many weapons already available from my previous work, however I cannot figure out how to procceed.
Any hand of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, set $E$ the matrix with all entries equal to $1$. Then, consider the matrix $C=-\frac{a}{Nab+b^{2}}E+\frac{1}{b}I$.
Now, of course it is easy to show that $E^{2}=NE$, a relation that we will need a bit later.
Also, we can write $B=aE+bI$

If we do the multiplication we will see that:
$$BC=(aE+bI)(-\frac{a}{Nab+b^{2}}E+\frac{1}{b}I)=-\frac{a^{2}NE}{Nab+b^{2}}+\frac{a}{b}E+I-\frac{ab}{Nab+b^{2}}=\frac{-a^{2}N+Na^{2}+ab-ab}{Nab+b^{2}}E+I=I$$

Therefore, $C=B^{-1}$ and thus we showed that $B^{-1}=-\frac{a}{Nab+b^{2}}E+\frac{1}{b}I$

Answer (score 2):

**Claim:** $$\mathbf B^{-1}=\frac{\mathrm{\mathbf{Id}}}{b}-\frac{a\mathbf M}{Nab+b^2},$$
where $\mathbf M$ is an $N\times N$ matrix with only ones as entries.

*Proof.* We need to prove that $\mathbf B$ multiplied by above candidate gives the identity, that is,
$$\left(b\mathrm{\mathbf {Id}}+a\mathbf M\right)\left(\frac{\mathrm{\mathbf{Id}}}{b}-\frac{a\mathbf M}{Nab+b^2}\right)=\mathrm{\mathbf {Id}},$$ or equivalently
$$(b\mathrm{\mathbf {Id}}+a\mathbf M)\left((Na+b)\mathrm{\mathbf {Id}}-a\mathbf M\right)=(Nab+b^2)\mathrm{\mathbf{Id}}$$
after multiplication by $Nab+b^2$. Using that $\mathbf M^2=N\mathbf M$ (this is easy to see, try it for instance with $N=3$), the expansion of the LHS gives
$$(Nab+b^2)\mathrm{\mathbf{Id}}-ab\mathbf M+(Na^2+ab)\mathbf M-a^2N\mathbf M=(Nab+b^2)\mathrm{\mathbf{Id}},$$
as required.$\qquad\tiny\blacksquare$

---

I was able to guess the candidate for $\mathbf B^{-1}$ by computing it manually for $N=1,2,3$ and seeing a pattern.